# Observer and Decorator used together c++ *REVISED*

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a program thats a coffee house that does beverage as a decorator / wrapper...

I also have a observer and i am trying to tie that in with beverage. so, when the order is placed cellphone one is notified. I dont know how to do the update..

if i pass TheOrder class i get errors!

beverage.h

```
#ifndef _BEVERAGE_
#define _BEVERAGE_

#include "Starbuzz.h"


namespace CoffeeHouse {
namespace Decorator {
    //namespace Observer {
    //using namespace std;

    class Beverage {

    protected: std::string _description;

    protected: Beverage() : 
        _description( "Unknown Beverage" ) {
        }
    public: virtual ~Beverage() = 0 {
            }
    public: virtual std::string getDescription() const {
                return _description;
            }
    public: virtual double cost() const = 0;
    };

} // namespace Observer
} // namespace CoffeeHouse
//}
#endif
```

one of the beverage concrete classes - i have 4 (espresso,houseblend,darkroast,decaf)

```
#ifndef _DARK_ROAST_
#define _DARK_ROAST_

#include "Starbuzz.h"

namespace CoffeeHouse {
namespace Decorator {
//namespace Observer {
class DarkRoast : public Beverage {

public: 

    DarkRoast() 
        {
    _description = "Dark Roast Coffee";
}
public: double cost() const {
    return 0.99;
}
};

} // namespace Observer
} 

#endif
```

beverage decorator

```
#ifndef _BEVERAGE_DECORATOR_
#define _BEVERAGE_DECORATOR_

#include "Starbuzz.h"


namespace CoffeeHouse {
namespace Decorator {

class BeverageDecorator : public Beverage {

private: BeverageDecorator( const BeverageDecorator& ); // Disable copy constructor
private: void operator=( const BeverageDecorator& ); // Disable assignment operator

protected: BeverageDecorator() {
}
public: virtual ~BeverageDecorator() = 0 {
};
public: virtual std::string getDescription() const = 0;
};
//}
} // namespace Observer
} // namespace CoffeeHouse

#endif
```

Here is the observer implementation..

Subject class

```
#ifndef _SUBJECT_
#define _SUBJECT_
#include "Observer.h"
#include <list>

namespace CoffeeHouse {
namespace Observers {

class Subject {

protected: virtual ~Subject() = 0 {
};
public: virtual void registerObserver( Observer* o ) = 0;
public: virtual void removeObserver( Observer* o ) = 0;
    public: virtual void notifyObservers() = 0;
};

} // namespace Observer
} 

#endif
```

here is the subject concrete class..

```
#ifndef _THE_ORDER_
#define _THE_ORDER_

#include "Beverage.h"
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include "Order.h"

#pragma once;

using namespace CoffeeHouse::Decorator;
namespace CoffeeHouse {
namespace Observers {


class TheOrder : public Subject {



 private: mutable std::list< Observer* > _observers;
//private: mutable std::list< Order* > _orders;

//public: virtual ~Order() = 0 
//public: ~TheOrder();
public: void NewOrder(Beverage* bev)
        {
            _orders.push_front(new Order(bev));
       //_observers.push_front(new Order(bev));

        }

public: void registerObserver( Observer* o ) { assert( o );
    _observers.push_back(o);
}

public: void removeObserver( Observer* o ) { assert( o );
    _observers.remove(o);
}

public: void notifyObservers()  {
    for( std::list< Observer* >::iterator iterator = _observers.begin(); _observers.end() != iterator; ++iterator ) {
        Observer* observer = *iterator;
        observer->update();

    }
}


};
//}
} // namespace Observer
} // namespace CoffeeHouse

#endif
```

here is cellphone1 which is the observer

```
#ifndef _CELLPHONE1_
#define _CELLPHONE1_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace CoffeeHouse {
namespace Observers {

class CellPhone1: public Observer {
public: 
    std::string _number;

    CellPhone1(std::string number){
        _number = number;
    }

    void update()
 {
     std::cout << "BUZZZZZZZ - CellPhone #" << _number << " your order is ready " << endl;
}
};

} // namespace Observer
} //

#endif
```

here is main()

```
#include "Starbuzz.h"
#include "Starbuzz2.h"
#include "Subject.h"

#include "TheOrder.h"
#include "CellPhone2.h"
#include "CellPhone3.h"
#include "CellPhone1.h"

using namespace CoffeeHouse::Decorator;
using namespace CoffeeHouse::Observers;


int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{


Beverage* beverage3 = new HouseBlend();
beverage3 = new Soy(beverage3);
beverage3 = new Mocha(beverage3);
beverage3 = new Whip(beverage3);
std::cout << beverage3->getDescription() 
    << " $" 
    << beverage3->cost() 
    << std::endl;

delete beverage3;
delete beverage2;
//delete beverage;



TheOrder* orders = new TheOrder();
CellPhone1* obj = new CellPhone1("1");
orders->registerObserver(obj);
orders->notifyObservers();

    Beverage* beverage6 = new DarkRoast();
orders->NewOrder(new Mocha(new Soy(new Whip((beverage6)))));


return 0;
```

}

here is the order class

```
#ifndef _ORDER_
#define _ORDER_
#include <iostream>
#include "Beverage.h"

namespace CoffeeHouse {
namespace Decorator {

class Order  {


     Beverage* _beverage;
public: 
    Order(Beverage* beverage)
    {
        _beverage = beverage;
    }




};
}
}
#endif
```

So, now i just need to do an update. what would i need to pass in update()?

i would like to pass in the order in update so cellphone can display the order. If try to pass in The order class i have to include "theorder.h" and then i get a zillion errors.

Comment: There are far too many independent questions here.  Please could you edit your post down considerably, and focus one specific issue?

Comment: I update it and changed some things sorry..

Comment: @icelated, tl;dr means "Too long;Didn't Read"..  I think you might need to be more concise and specific in your question.  Right now, I have no idea what I am answering...

Comment: More isn't always better.  It seems like you're getting a compiler error, so you should start diagnosing your problem by asking us a question about how to resolve your compiler error.  To do this, you should break your code down **(omitting as much as possible, while still getting the error)**, and then post *only* the offending code.  If its more than 10-15 lines, then you're less likely to get help.  Then, give us **the exact error**, and which line it occurred on.  Doing this will maximize your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: I totally revised it. its very simplistic now.. thank you

Comment: It is still nearly impossible to understand the question.   I would suggest removing the classes `Beverage`, `DarkRoast`, `BeverageDecorator`, `Subject`, and `main()` as they have nothing to do with the problem.  Then, in `TheOrder.h` try to replace `#include "Order.h"` with `class Order;` and see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few comments to help make the source code more readable :

1.) You do not have to explicitly declare "access specifier" (public/protected/private) for each method/attribute. By default, class has "private" specifier and it will be applied repeatedly until another declaration is encountered.

2.) If the code snippet belongs to specific source file, tell us the filename instead of having us guessing it.

3.) Try to avoid indirect inclusion (as in the depended header is included by another file). In your current project, all your classes depends on "Starbuzz.h" and it is hard for us to interpret the order of inclusion manually. You may also want to learn more on **Forward Declaration**.